# Installing jdk17 on Mac with brew

Tags: java, macos, homebrew

I am trying to install jdk17 with brew, while also having java8, java11 and java16 installed.

In order to install 8, 11 and 16 I ran:

```
brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk

brew install --cask adoptopenjdk8

brew install --cask adoptopenjdk11

brew install --cask adoptopenjdk16
```

However there seems to be no adoptopenjdk for 17.

I can install 17 with

```
brew install openjdk
```

But if I run

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 17
```

it returns

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-16.jdk/Contents/Home
```

and there is no entry for 17 in

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
```

I am using

```
alias java8="unset JAVA_HOME; export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`; java -version"
alias java11="unset JAVA_HOME; export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11`; java -version"
alias java16="unset JAVA_HOME; export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 16`; java -version"
alias java17="unset JAVA_HOME; export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 17`; java -version"
```

to manage the java versions, and without an entry for java 17, I can't switch to it.

Thanks.

Comment: They changed their name to [Temurin](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/adoptium.temurin). I use [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/) to manage my JVM on mac. I suggest you do too. See [supported JDKs](https://sdkman.io/jdks).

Comment: Seems like sdkman wants the version as X.Y.Z. I'd like to be able to install all the LTEs from 8 (8, 11, 17) + the latest one, and be able to easily update them, without knowing the minor versions. Is that possible with sdkman ?

Comment: Install the version explicitly. When you do an `sdk upgrade` it will (by default) always recommend the latest version of Temurin. At least at the moment.

Comment: Did you ever get alias java17 working like you want? If so, please update. Thanks.

Answer (score 68):

So, noone wastes more time on this, to install temurin17, execute:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew install --cask temurin17
```

Comment: Worth noting, for those new to Homebrew like me, that the first command downloads available versions. Otherwise Brew only knows about the latest and it says something like `Cask 'temurin17' is unavailable`.

Answer (score 30):

**Update!**

The new website for this project is [here called Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/) (thanks @MarkRotteveel). In Homebrew, the package that installs the new AdoptOpenJDK is [here named temurin](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/temurin#default). All you need to run is:

```
brew install --cask temurin17
```

or for the latest version

```
brew install --cask temurin
```

Comment: The AdoptOpenJDK project has been renamed to Adoptium (as shown in the banner on the link in your answer), and can now be found on https://adoptium.net/.

Comment: This currently installs version 18. For 17 use `temurin17` via tap `homebrew/cask-versions`

Comment: I had to run
`brew tap homebrew/cask-versions`

To get this to work. Maybe that's obvious to those familiar with homebrew, but I had to dig a bit.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks everyone this was very helpful.  I also had to make the following changes to my `$HOME/.zshrc` file

```
export PATH="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/:$PATH"
```

I also kept my old adoptopenjdk8 on my system but commented out this line from `$HOME/.zshrc` to remove java 8 from my path so it would not be executed when I ran java command

```
# export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk@8/bin:$PATH"
```

to execute my PATH with these 2 changes I ran

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Prior to this I ran these 2 command to get java 17 installed

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew info temurin17
brew install temurin17
```

now (as of April 12, 2023) when I run

```
java -version
```

it shows

```
openjdk version "17.0.6" 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.6+10 (build 17.0.6+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.6+10 (build 17.0.6+10, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Prior to this `java -version` showed

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_362"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_362-bre_2023_01_22_03_32-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.362-b00, mixed mode)
```

the

```
brew info temurin17
```

command shows you what brew "knows" about `temurin17` and the output I had before I installed it was

```
==> temurin17: 17.0.6,10
https://adoptium.net/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions/blob/HEAD/Casks/temurin17.rb
==> Name
Eclipse Temurin Java Development Kit
==> Description
JDK from the Eclipse Foundation (Adoptium)
==> Artifacts
OpenJDK17U-jdk_x64_mac_hotspot_17.0.6_10.pkg (Pkg)
```

FYI If you do not have `brew` installed on your mac simply run

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend installing jEnv to manage and select from multiple installed JDKs. When later versions are released you can easily switch between prior versions.

$ brew install jenv

jEnv is a command line tool to help you forget how to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable

https://www.jenv.be/

Comment: Can it manage other JVMs than Oracle ones ?

Comment: Yes  not a problem